# How to find $x(t)$ in:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ok people, trying to fix my question before I have the following problem:

I need to find $ x(t) $ so I can evaluate it in $t=t_f$ integrating (with respect to $t$) $\int_0^{t_f}\int \ddot x(t) \, dt$ either numerically or not.

$\ddot{x} = x\dot{\alpha}^2 + k$ ; $k={}$constant

and

$\dot{\alpha}(t) = a+ bt $  ; $a,b ={}$constants

so in other words I need to integrate

$\ddot{x} = x( a+ bt )^2 + k$

do I need extra information to solve this or it can be done? 
thanks a lot.

Comment: With respect to t

Comment: Is there any more context to the problem? I don't it is solvable with the info present as we cannot write $x$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem I don't have x in terms of t, otherwise would be straightforward. This is the inward acceleration of a object inspiraling in, in a circular motion. So that will gives me the position of the object while is falling in.

Comment: the other information I have is that $x\dot{\alpha}^2 < C $ ; c=constant. I am not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: If it is the inward acceleration, then it is equal to $x = \frac{mv^2}{r}$, which might be of some use. Please post the problem in its entirety.